# How can I integrate Spotify client with Wingpanel?

Tags: applications, wingpanel, spotify

I installed Spotify using the [official repository](https://www.spotify.com/us/download/linux/) but the icon does not appear in Wingpanel. Someone with the same issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spotify client is a QT-based application which relies on `sni-qt` to display it's indicator icon. Maybe somehow `sni-qt` got removed by uninstalling another application on your machine.

Check if `sni-qt` is installed:

```
dpkg -l | grep sni-qt
```

In case it's not, reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt
```

Comment: Hi, I install Spotify from this tutorial http://linuxpitstop.com/install-spotify-client-1-x-beta-on-ubuntu-15-04/ because I have 32 bit and work 100% but I want to integrate with the wingpanel, I have installed sni-qt but doesn't show in the bar