# Spotify icon tray

Tags: wingpanel, spotify

With the new Spotify update, the icon tray is gone does anyone know how to put it back? I know that elementary OS doesn't have a system tray icon, but I'm used to have the spotify icon on the top right corner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I integrate Spotify client with Wingpanel?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/290/how-can-i-integrate-spotify-client-with-wingpanel)

Comment: @bitseater nop, spotify removed the sistem tray icon with the new update from yesterday

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the new update has removed the old icon tray, more info [here](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Windows-Web/Linux-Spotify-client-1-x-now-in-stable/td-p/1300404)

Now I was used to use the icon tray to pause/play forward and rewind musics.

Based on one of the comments on the forum I was wable to create actions to the spotify icon on the dock.

First do open the spotify.desktop

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/spotify.desktop
```

Then at this at the end of the file

```
Actions=PlayOrPause;Next;Previous

[Desktop Action PlayOrPause]
Name=Play or Pause
Exec=dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause
[Desktop Action Next]
Name=Next
Exec=dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Next
[Desktop Action Previous]
Name=Previous
Exec=dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Previous
```

**Bonus:**
If you want you can add some icons to your actions:

```
Icon=media-playback-start
Icon=media-skip-forward
Icon=media-skip-backward
```

So it will be something like this:

```
Actions=PlayOrPause;Next;Previous

[Desktop Action PlayOrPause]
Icon=media-playback-start
Name=Play or Pause
Exec=dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.PlayPause
[Desktop Action Next]
Icon=media-skip-forward
Name=Next
Exec=dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Next
[Desktop Action Previous]
Icon=media-skip-backward
Name=Previous
Exec=dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Previous
```

[image: result of actions]

Comment: To take an actual screenshot, use the screenshot app with a timed delay, then open the right-click menu.

Comment: @LewisGoddard How do you do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, how do I use the screenshot app? Just search in the applications menu.

Comment: @LewisGoddard never mind after 2 years of using eOS I had never noticed the screenshot app. Changed to a proper screenshot