# How to display kazam in tray

Tags: wingpanel

When I'm starting to record in kazam it's hidden. When I was on Ubuntu i had it in the tray, but now it's hidden in an unknown (for me) place.

How can I display it in the tray?

I tried the answers to [this question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/how-can-i-get-applications-to-display-a-system-tray-icon) and [this one](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4574/spotify-icon-tray) but they didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About system tray icons. In [release-juno](/questions/tagged/release-juno), elementaryOS dropped the support of the old Ayatana Indicators

While the software devs implement the new way you can have them back by...

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yunnxx/elementary
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install indicator-application wingpanel-indicator-ayatana
```

then you need to edit a file (i used nano, use any editor you want - avoiding a holy war)

```
$ sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop
```

find the line

```
OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;
```

and add `Pantheon`

```
OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;Pantheon;
```

that's it, just restart X and you will have the old notification area icons

---

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/17453/14940